# scala Play Anorm parser throws UnexpectedNullableFound in model

Tags: scala, playframework, anorm

The Unexpected UnexpectedNullableFound(post.IMAGE) i got this error 
while running the program, and couldn't identify what is the error ,
If anyone  got the same error or know the detail of the error please mention here

and my database is MySql

My Model class ,

```
case class Post(id: Pk[Long]= NotAssigned, name:String, image:String)
```

The function

```
def listAllPostById():List[Post]={
    DB.withConnection{ implicit connection =>
      val listpost =SQL(
          """
          select * from POST 
          """).on(
              ).as(Post.simple.*)
    listpost     
    }
```

in application the method calling

```
def listAllpost()= Action{
    val post:List[Post]=Post.listAllPostById
    Ok(views.html.allPosts.render(post))
   }
```

and in routes

```
GET  /allPosts    controllers.Application.listAllpost
```

And View page

```
@for(post:Post<- posts){
@post.id
@post.name
@post.image}
```

Simple method

```
 val simple ={
    get[Pk[Long]]("post.id") ~
    get[String]("post.name")~
    get[String]("post.image") map {
      case id ~ name ~ image => Post(id,name,image)
    }
```

Error

```
Execution exception

[RuntimeException: UnexpectedNullableFound(post.IMAGE)]
```

Error on line

```
   ).as(Post.simple.*)
```

advnce
   thnx.. by prasanth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is error in your simple method. You must take care about your table name and column name, and type of column which you fetched from DB in simple function. In case if you are not sure that row have values for all columns or not you should use Option so may be there you catch this error due to unavailability of data.

You should ensure in simple function about get[DATA TYPE] or  get[Option[DATA TYPE]]